# crystal report with dynamic parameter for each page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using asp.net 4.0. visual studio 2010. I have to make a report for more than one customer. each customer will choose more than one product.  My condition is one page must contain only one customers purchase details (this purchase may be more than one.) and in the next page for next customer purchases.. like wise I have to develop report.

> I got all customer's purchase list in a dataset. but, when displaying
>   it shows all customers purchase detail continuously from the first
>   page itself.
>
> How to aggregate it in crystal report. And report customer name wise.

Anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a group by `Customer` and for that group go to section expert and in `paging tab`
check `New Page After` so that every customer will come in new page. If you don't require supress group footer.